# Loading json data in apache_superset in key value format

Tags: python, json, postgresql, apache-superset

I have a json structure like this in the postgres db table. I want to analyse this result in apache-superset in a structured format where i can get the category subcategory and value.
This is dynamic table so the keys and values can be different for each row where the name of the category is "result".

[{"name": "result", "label": "result", "value": "{"tech_rating":{"java":"1","python":"1"}}"}, {"name": "id", "label": "id", "value": "4"}]
[{"name": "result", "label": "result", "value": "{"tech_rating1":{"java":"2","python":"2","go":"2"},"int_rating1":{"java":"2","python":"2","go":"2"},"tech_rating2":{"spring":"2","superset":"2"},"int_rating2":{"spring":"2","superset":"2"}}"}, {"name": "id", "label": "id", "value": "5"}]
[{"name": "result", "label": "result", "value": "{"tech_rating":{"java":"1","python":"1","go":"1"}}"}, {"name": "id", "label": "id", "value": "6"}]

So the desired output is in this format

| cat | sub cat | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| tech_rating | java | 1 |
| tech_rating | python | 1 |
| tech_rating1 | java | 2 |
| tech_rating1 | python | 2 |
| tech_rating3 | go | 2 |
| int_rating1 | java | 2 |
| int_rating1 | python | 2 |
| int_rating1 | go | 2 |
| tech_rating2 | spring | 2 |
| tech_rating2 | superset | 2 |
| tech_rating | java | 1 |
| tech_rating | python | 1 |
| tech_rating | go | 1 |

Comment: I don't have a good solution for your case.  However, I would recommend that you create a _view_ in the form you want in the postgres table, then ingest the data in the proper format.